# How to handle with "in class" imbalance in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, unbalanced-classes, supervised-learning

A lot is written about class imbalance in machine learning [(for example on this site here)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131255/class-imbalance-in-supervised-machine-learning).

However, **how to deal with "intra class" imbalance?**

Assume I want to classify Bikes v.s. Cars. My training/test data is 50% about bikes and 50% cars (no class imbalance). However of this 50% cars, I have 1% Formule 1 cars, 70% small cars, 20% SUVs, 7% pick up cars and 2% jeeps.

There is no class imbalance, but what I call 'intra class' imbalance.

My question:

- Is this from a ML/statistics point of view a problem? Why is it or why is it not?
- What is the name/keyword for this problem what I call 'intra class imbalance'?

Comment: I would regard this as regular class imbalance since it will have the same type of effects. To be dealt with in the same fashion as regular class imbalance.

Comment: What would be the issues in using the same solution as inter class imbalance problems?