# How to undersample with algorithms in R to solve class imbalance?

Tags: r, algorithms, subsampling

My data set is imbalanced - 5% of the target class represents fraudulent transactions, 95% of the target class represents legitimate transactions.
I must use the whole data set, as the 95% of legitimate transactions are important for training.
How can I use undersampling within algorithms such as rpart (decision tree), naive bayes, neural networks, SVM, etc. to create, run and evaluate using multiple splits of the data.
For example:  the number of legitimate transactions is equal to the number of fraudulent. So 5% and 5%. 
This is instead of the typical way of cutting down the data set to 50% legitimate, 50% fraud where you would lose 85% of the legitimate transactions.
I cannot oversample by generating randomized data in this case.

[image: undersampled data set]

Answer (score 1):

First off, 95%-5% is NOT an example of imbalanced dataset, I would consider downsampling if there was something of the order of 99.9%-0.1%. Most approaches should work just fine.

Edit: Seems like this answer has this covered already, have a look here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133385/41367;

Now, if you *have* to rebalance, here are some options:

1. Weight the infrequent class
2. Stratified Sampling to downsize the frequent class
3. Balanced subsampling to create multiple random balanced subsamples, then bootstrapping, ensembling (eg. Random Forests) etc.

From what I interpret, 3rd point should address your question about undersampling *within* the algorithm.

Comment: 95%-5% it's definitely not an example of balanced dataset either. You would get probably 100 percent of your samples predicted as majority class by any not cost sensitive classifier

Comment: Of course it isnt, if you were to take it literally. So, you are saying a coin toss with 95% probability of heads would be better than using any non-cost sensitive classifier?

Comment: @rep_ho The issue here is seeking hard classification without first fitting a probability model.  If you do your modeling properly, 95%-5% is no problem for most probabilistic models.  Cost optimization should be performed subsequent to a probabalistic model of your data.

Comment: That is true, but that was not mentioned in the question or the answer. If you are doing classifier, not a probabilistic model, most approaches will not work fine out of the box. But i agree that modeling probability should often prefered

Comment: Classifiers typically develop probability models implicitly so there is no need for an explicit model anyway. I'm curious, can you provide an example of a (out-of-the-box?) classifier that does not implicitly use a probability model?