# The Best Approach for the Classification of the imbalanced classes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, data-mining, pattern-recognition

I have data that I am going to classify to 3 classes, but one class has a few samples less than 5% of the total samples. What is the best approach to classify these imbalanced classes? 
I mean is there a machine learning technique that fits this case or is there any other procedures to improve the classification?

Comment: It is a supervened learning, the labels are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the imbalanced data you need to treat the classification task differently. For example monitoring your accuracy might tell you, you're doing well, although you never correctly classify the 5%. One option I used before was resampling, but I think there is good post in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131255/class-imbalance-in-supervised-machine-learning) and [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/).

Comment: If I used Random Forest....are the approaches of the oversampling and the under sampling of the data needed?

Answer (score 0):

When using Random Forests (or any other ensemble method), you can use one of the following (or both) approaches:

#### Adapt the prior probabilities

Use this option if some classes are under- or overrepresented in your training set. Most training algorithms can handle this.

#### Adapt the missclassification cost

If classes are adequately represented in the training data but you want to treat them asymmetrically, use the cost parameter $C$. Given you have a two class problem:

$$C = \left[
\begin{matrix}
0 &  c_{0,1} \\
c_{1,0}  &  0
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

where $c_{i,j} > 1$ is the cost of missclassifying class $i$ as $j$. Note, that the penalty on the diagonal is 0, because it means that the classification was correct, i.e. $i = j$.

#### Adapt the Training Algorithm

You can emply the RUSBoost Algorithm by [Seiffert et al.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220928945_RUSBoost_Improving_Classification_Performance_when_Training_Data_is_Skewed), which can handle imbalanced data pretty well.

#### Further Reading

Matlab has a great section on this. You can find it [here.](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/ensemble-methods.html#btfwpd3)