# Classification on highly skewed dataset

Tags: logistic, classification, skewness, naive-bayes

I have two classes A and B. 98% of the data belongs to class A and 2% of it belongs to class B. Size of the entire dataset is about 2000. I am interested in correctly classifying all the data points that belong to class B.

I want to perform classification on the aforementioned dataset but I am not sure whether the classification techniques such as Naive Bayes, Logistic Regression will work on my dataset.

Could you suggest me some technique through which I can perform the classification on the aforementioned dataset?

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered before. Search old posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class imbalance in Supervised Machine Learning](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131255/class-imbalance-in-supervised-machine-learning)

Comment: ‘I am interested in correctly classifying all the data points that belong to class B.` Then label everything as belonging to class B. If this is not viable (I know it probably isn’t), it will be illuminating to read your explanation about why.