# Classification Tree Predictions

Tags: r, classification, cart

I have a question about using cross-validation to assess results estimated
from a classification tree model. I annotated what each line does in the R
code chunk below. Basically, I split the data, named usedta, into 70% vs.
30%, with the training set having 70% and the test set 30% of the original
cases. After splitting the data, I first run a classification tree off the
training set, and then use the results for cross-validation using the test
set. It turns out that if I don't have any predictors and make predictions
by simply betting on the majority class of the zero-one coding of the
binary response variable, I can do better than what the results from the
classification tree would deliver in the test set. What would this imply
and what would cause this problem? Does it mean that classification tree is
not an appropriate method for my data; or, it's because I have too few
variables?

Using the estimates, I get the following prediction rate (correct
prediction) using the test set. Or we can say the misclassification error
rate is 1-0.837 = 0.163

```
(tab[1,1] + tab[2,2]) / sum(tab)
[1] 0.837
```

Without any predictors, I can get the following rate by betting on the
majority class every time, again using data from the test set. In this
case, the misclassification error rate is 1-0.85 = 0.15

```
table(h2.test)

1poorHlth 0goodHlth
      101       575 

571/(571+101)
[1] 0.85
```

R Code Chunk:

```r
set.seed(47306)
# have the 7/3 split with 70% of the cases allotted to the training set
# AND create the training set identifier
class.train = sample(1:nrow(usedta), nrow(usedta)*0.7)
# create the test set indicator
class.test = (-class.train)
# create a vector for the binary response variable from the test set
# for future cross-tabulation.
h2.test <- usedta$h2[class.test]
# count the train set cases
Ntrain = length(usedta$h2[class.train])
# run the classification tree model using the training set
# h2 is the binary response and other variables are predictors
tree.h2 <- tree(h2 ~ age + educ + female + white + married + happy,
                data = usedta, subset = class.train,
                control = tree.control(nobs=Ntrain, mindev=0.003))
# summary results
summary(tree.h2)
# make predictions of h2 using the test set
tree.h2.pred <- predict(tree.h2, usedta[class.test,], type="class")
# cross tab the predictions using the test set
table(tree.h2.pred, h2.test)
tab = table(tree.h2.pred, h2.test)
# calculate the ratio for the correctly predicted in the test set
(tab[1,1] + tab[2,2]) / sum(tab)
# calculate the ratio for the correctly predicted using the naive approach
# by betting on the majority category.
table(h2.test)[2]/sum(tab)
```

Comment: seems like you have an dataset with class imbalance. running the rpart will only bias towards the majority class.. One thing you can try to do is set a higher weight on the minor class.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131255/class-imbalance-in-supervised-machine-learning

Comment: Hi StupidWolf, Thanks a lot for your pointers! I will give your question and its posts a close read.